# why my cron job is not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, console, command

in db i have column `visit_clear` i want it 0 after one day so i used this code
in kernal.php

```
   <?php
    
    namespace App\Console;
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
    
    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        protected $commands = [
        ];
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->command('cron:update-user-not-new')->daily();
        }
    
        protected function commands()
        {
            $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
    
            require base_path('routes/console.php');
        }
    }
```

and in command/UpdateUserNotNew.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UpdateUserNotNew extends Command
{
 
    protected $signature = 'cron:update-user-not-new';

    protected $description = 'Command description';



    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $dayAgo = 1; // Days ago
        $dayToCheck = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($dayAgo)->format('Y-m-d');
        Customer::whereDate('visit_date', '<=', $dayToCheck)
        ->update([
            'visit_clear' => 0
        ]);
    }
}
```

i am sheduling commnd like this as u can see `cron:update-user-not-new` should i use `crone:UpdateUserNotNew`?

Comment: Have you started the scheduler as described in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Have you registered the command in `Console\Kernel.php` in the `$commands` array, and within your command class what is the value of `$signature`

Comment: first time i am working on it (cron) so no idea is it started u can check complete code updated

Comment: To see if you cron job works on local you need just to execute in terminal inside your project folder: `php artisan cron:update-user-not-new`

Comment: If it works you have to add Cron entry to your server.
Example: [Laravel Cron Jobs Scheduling](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-cron-job-scheduling/)
Anyway first of all read the docs because youll never get the idea behind it. [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction)

Comment: ok thanx for your contribution @MarinarioAgalliu i test it locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your command in `Kernel.php` like this:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\UpdateUserNotNew',
];
```

You should then be able to run the command manually with `php artisan cron:update-user-not-new`

In order for the automatic running of the command to work, you need to add an entry to your system's task scheduler, as this is what Laravel uses to run commands on a schedule.

Assuming you are using Linux, you need to add an entry to your crontab. To do this, in a command prompt enter `crontab -e`, hit enter, and add this line:

`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Don't forget to replace `/path-to-your-project` with the root folder of your project
Once done editing the crontab, save and close the editor and the new entries should be installed, and your command should now run on the schedule.

All this info came from https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling so if you need more info take a look there